# Как сделать сохранение рекорда?

Tags: python

Как сделать сохранение рекорда?

```
import random
import sys
import time
D=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
while True:
    print('Loegin...')
    time.sleep(10)
    X=(random.randint(1,100))
    print('Наилучшее время  %s' %(D))
    t1=time.time()
    while True:
        print('Отгадайте число от 1 до 100')
        A=int(sys.stdin.readline())
        if A<X:
            print('Загаданное число больше')
        if A>X:
            print('Загаданное число меньше')
        if A==X:
            t2=time.time()
            C=t2-t1
            print('Прошло %s секунд' %(t2-t1))
            if C<float(D):
                print('Поздравляю! У вас новый рекорд!')
                D=C
                break
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import sys
import time
try:
    with open('best.txt', 'r') as file: D=float(file.read().split('\n')[0])
except: D=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while True:
    print('Loading...')
    time.sleep(10)
    X=(random.randint(1,100))
    print('Наилучшее время  %s' %(D))
    t1=time.time()
    while True:
        print('Отгадайте число от 1 до 100')
        A=int(input())
        if A<X: print('Загаданное число больше')
        if A>X: print('Загаданное число меньше')
        if A==X:
            C=time.time()-t1
            print('Прошло %s секунд' %(C))
            if C<float(D):
                print('Поздравляю! У вас новый рекорд!')
                D=C
                with open('best.txt', 'w') as file: file.write(str(D))
            break
```

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо!